# AngularJS not displaying images from API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

In my current scenario im just displaying images from rest api. But it dumping`error 403`. Here is my [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/23oLmek4/1/). Have a look on it , I have tried

`<img src=""` and also `ng-src=''` too but still not fetching images from URLs. it is giving these errors: http://prntscr.com/h1kjt3

Positive response will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Everything seems to work in the fiddle?

Comment: it is not displaying images.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/h1kjt3

Comment: It's the actual image link that's not working

Comment: if we open all those URLs in next tab they do work.

Comment: It does not display images because there are no images. I tried to open https://buyfansfollower.com/snapmojo/uploads/2/2_20171024201244_57656_2043362779282770.jpg for example... and got 502 Bad gateway.

Comment: Oops, after that, it opens, but others not.

Comment: opening here on myside :O

Comment: buyfansfollower.com does not allow hot linking

Comment: in network tab , it is saying URLs type as text. not url :(

Comment: I don't know waht the Problem, but when you open an image direct with like, after that this image work

Comment: @FerhadOthman this is exactly problem.

Comment: Looks like an image hosting issue

Comment: My vps guy told me Hot linking is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloudflare hosted website have an option to **Hotlink Protection** option. When enabled other websites cannot load these images. Here is a [good article](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170026-What-does-enabling-Cloudflare-Hotlink-Protection-do-) explaining.

If it is your website, you can disable **Hotlink Protection**. If not you cannot use them.

Answer (score 0):

by using this directive it works:

```
app.directive('ngSrc', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('error', function() {
                if (attrs.src != attrs.ngSrc) {
                     window.location.href=attrs.ngSrc;

                }
            });
        }
    }
})
```